# Parsing html with php and ganon

Tags: php, parsing

please help me to change selector for my code.

I try to get sellen name from page http://www.plati.ru/asp/seller.asp?id_s=119777

It's must be **amedia**, but I can't to get it.

This is my code

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$html = str_get_dom($result );

foreach ($html('table tr td tr td') as $element) {
    $seller_name = $element->getPlainText();
}
```

Comment: Maybe that would be: body table tbody tr td table tbody tr td ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following and let me know if you still have any difficulties,

```
include "ganon.php";
$shopUrl = "http://www.plati.ru/asp/seller.asp?id_s=119777";
$html = file_get_dom($shopUrl);
echo $html('table',9)->getPlainText();
```

Comment: its my pleasure pal. happy coding

Answer (score 0):

you can use `DomDocument` like this code to retrieve the td value :

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    $DOM = new DOMDocument;
    @$DOM->loadHTMLFile('http://www.plati.ru/asp/seller.asp?id_s=119777');

    $tables = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('table');//->item(10);
    $table = $tables->item(9);
    $cells = $table->getElementsByTagName('td');
    $cell = $cells->item(0);
    echo $cell->textContent; 
?>
```

the split the `$cell->textContent` using spaces.